# How to transform a normalised data set using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pivot, normalization

Here are my tables:

users table

```
id   |   name  
1    |   john  
2    |   lucy
```

user_accounts table

```
id   |   user_id    |   account_name
1          2             lucy_lu
2          1             johndoe
```

account_parameters table

```
id   |  account_id  |  parameter_id   |  value
1           1              10             4000
2           1              11             1450
3           2              10             5000
4           2              11             1150
```

parameters table

```
id   |   parameter_value  |  parameter_name
10          height               Height
11          max_score            Max Score
```

I want to get result:

```
user_id | user_name | account_name |  Height  |  Max Score
1          john        johndoe        5000       1150
2          lucy        lucy_lu        4000       1450
```

I searched for "mysql generate columns with data" and similar, found many solutions for 1 or 2 tables, but I don't know how to implement those here. I know how to select static fields with joins, but I don't know how to select "Height" and "Max Score" in this example.

Comment: What about GROUP BY?

Comment: I think height for user_id 1 should be 4000 and other data too

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - `account_id = 1` maps to `user_id = 2` maps to `name = lucy` => Lucy is user_id 2 and has a height of 4000.

Comment: @Alex, yes, PHP (laravel) in this case. .@MatBailie I thought about it in that way but still thinking of specific PHP way to do it...

Comment: @wast - then mark this as PHP and ask how to transform a normalised data set using PHP?

Comment: @wast search for query pivot data. that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: show us your current php code fragment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *must* do this using SQL, then using PHP that writes SQL seems to be the least tightly coupled approach.

First, query your parameters table and store in an array.

Then build your query string in three parts, the middle part being dynamically created.

```
SELECT
    user_accounts.user_id          AS user_id,
    user.name                      AS user_name,
    user_accounts.account_name     AS account_name,
```

Repeat this for each record in your array *(that came from `parameters`)*.

```
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN account_parameters.parameter_id = @param_id
             THEN account_parameters.value
        END
    )   AS @param_name,
```

Using PHP to substitute in the @param_id and @param_name values.

(Be careful of the commas, you don't want one on your last line of SQL.)

```
FROM
    account_parameters
INNER JOIN
    user_accounts
        ON  user_accounts.id = account_parameters.account_id
INNER JOIN
    user
        ON  user.id = user_accounts.user_id
GROUP BY
    user_accounts.user_id,
    user.name,
    user_accounts.account_name
```

*Note:* In MySQL you only really need to `GROUP BY user_accounts.user_id`, but I don't recommend *ab*using that feature in general.

Executing that dynamically built query should pivot your results for you.

You may need some context sensitivity to determine which parameters you do and do not want to include in your final results *(with this structure it seems likely that you won't always want all parameters)*.

Comment: This is working. However, I used MAX instead of SUM. Because with SUM I can't get string values. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since I did something similar, here is something to begin with:

```
$parameters = array(
       array("id" => 10, "parameter_value" => "height", "parameter_name" => "Height"),
       array("id" => 11, "parameter_value" => "max_score", "parameter_name" => "Max Score")
); //fetch all parameters from your parameters table

//specify the table where the values are stored
$tableName = 'account_parameters';
//specify the column name in this table where the identifier for your data lies
$dataIdColumnName = 'account_id';

//set the first column up, which holds your datakey
$selectPivotFields = array("`".$tableName."`.`".$dataIdColumnName."`");

//loop over all parameters  
if(is_array($parameters))
    for($i=0;$i<count($parameters);$i++)
    {
        //build a part of your pivot query
        $selectPivotFields[] = sprintf("MAX(IF(`%1$s`.`parameter_id` = '%2$d', `%1$s`.`value`, NULL)) AS `%3$s`", $tableName, $parameters[$i]['id'], $parameters[$i]['parameter_value']);
    }

    //build the actual query for readability i simplified it a little bit
    $sql = sprintf("
              SELECT
                %1$s
               FROM
                `%2$s`
               WHERE
                `%2$s`.`%3$s` = '%4$d'
               GROUP BY
                `%2$s`.`%3$s`
              ", implode(", ", $selectPivotFields), $tableName, $dataIdColumnName, $dataId);

     //and execute your query with the prefered class
     $result = execute($sql);
```

basically, it's the same background than the answer from [MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32400245/3641016)